# Change font-size transition direction

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I am trying to make it so that when someone hovers over a link in a certain div the font size will increase slightly. I have done this using:

```
footer #mid .box ul li a:hover {
color: #ccc;
transform: translate(2%);
font-size:25px;
}
```

The issue that I am having is that when the size increases it is always increasing in the same direction, so instead of the size increasing on all four sides it only increase on the left side and the bottom side. Is there a way for me to make the change equal on all sizes or at least control which side increases? I currently am using absolute positioning for these elements if that matters.

Comment: Have a look at the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) documentation. Is the transform part of the CSS essential for your problem?

Comment: It was not essential, but it was an effect that I wanted to happen upon hovering. If you see the answer and comments below the solution is outlined there without removing the transform in my css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align: left/right/center;` on the element to align the font to left, right or center. Then font will increase size in the opposite direction or both (for center alignment). Otherwise, you will have to move the element at the same time in the direction opposite the size change with translate or top/left

Comment: That works great for adjusting to the left and right, but I still have the issue of them increasing down but not up. Is there a way to alter that as well?

Comment: try with vertical-align. Results are not optimal, but it might work for you.

Comment: That did not work, but after messing around with the translateY option I was able to make it work.